# REST API for delete by specific field of the entity

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, endpoint

I'm developing a *DELETE API* for my service. 
I have read some docs and articles and didn't find a good description on how to design API for *DELETE* method if we need to delete an entity not by id, but by another field.

For example, I have an entity called "*Person*". It has "*id*" and "*group*". 
I want to have two delete methods.

1. Delete user by **ID**;
2. Delete users by **group**;

It's not a problem to delete by ID:

```
@DeleteMapping("/persons/{personId}")
```

However, to delete via another property, the best solution that I found was using request params. e.g.

```
DELETE /persons/?group=groupValue
```

That's totally fine to use such a way, but I wonder if there is more convenient way, maybe more clear and explicit one, to solve this task?

Comment: DELETE :  /persons/group/{groupValue}

Comment: Is that a common practice? I thought about this, but I've never seen someone building DELETE api like that in their projects.

Comment: it's not common practice. it's just variant. common practice - it's how you use it in your projects , follow convention that it appropriate for your team

Comment: The question is. How does your API look like when searching users by `group`? If it is using query (request) param then do the same for DELETE operation. Personally I think using query (request) param is the right way to do it.

Comment: we use params. However, since we are developing micro services, in new projects it makes sense use the best approaches